# Insert shortcode in widget area

Tags: shortcode

I enabled the Insert Pages plugin wich allows to create a shortcode for a given page e.g.: `[insert page='7' display='all']`.

See my capture of the setting of the plugin: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx1wywZmQareUHZhSmtlYWxiZlU/view?usp=sharing

Then, I added a "Text Html" widget to the Sidebar area with this text: `[insert page='7' display='all']`. What I need is to show the full content of that page (page id =7) in this area.

But the page is not shown, I just see the shortcode as it: [insert page='7' display='all'].

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't understand why I get downvotes. My question is clear and the answer I got is useful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortcodes are not parsed in widget text - you need to tell WordPress to do so:

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
```

Place it in your theme's `functions.php`